# Poner a esta funcion mysqli mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql

tengo esta funcion para insertar en myqli

```
function Insertar_Datos() { global $Conectar;
    $Parametros = func_get_args();
            $InDatos = "INSERT INTO `".$Parametros[0]."` (".$Parametros[1].") VALUES (".$Parametros[2].");";
            $RDatos = mysqli_query($Conectar, $InDatos);
            if (!$RDatos) { http_response_code(500); print(mysqli_error($Conectar)); } else { http_response_code(200); echo "ok"; }
     return $RDatos;
}
```

la forma de usar la funcion estoy usando esta:

```
$InuevoArticulo = Insertar_Datos("Tabla" , "`id`,`nombre`" , "'".mysqli_real_escape_string($Conectar, $_POST['id'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($Conectar, $_POST['nombre'])."'");
```

Como veis hasta ahora en parámetros[2] meto todo el codigo con el real scape bla bla bla... 
¿habria alguna forma de que en parámetros[2] solo ponga $_POST['lo_que_sea'] y que escriba en el insert todo el codigo de mysqli_real_escape_string($Conectar,... automáticamente?

Mil gracias por vuestra ayuda :)

Comment: Por qué al definir la función no tiene parámetros pero al usarla le pasas varios?

Comment: los capturo usando $Parametros = func_get_args(); entonces a la hora de llamar a la función simplemente los separo por coma y para recuperarlos le digo la posicion de lo que quiero recuperar y listo :) parámetros[2], parámetros[1], etc

Comment: Seria mas fácil si `$Parametros[2]` fuera un arreglo con todos los datos a guardar. Es mas, si fuera un arreglo asociativo, te podrías ahorrar `$Parametros[1]`, es decir: `Insertar_Datos("Tabla", array('id'=> $_POST['id'], ...)`, luego simplemente seria iterar el arreglo y armar ambas cadenas

Comment: @MarcosGallardo No se exactamente como seria, pero me encanta la idea de poder definir las tablas de mysql y el valor tipo array que eso me quitaría el tener que estar pendiente de si he puesto el valor en sitio correcto o las malditas comillas. Voy a investigar un poco a ver si soy capaz de hacerlo.

Answer (score 2):

En la [documentación oficial](http://php.net/manual/es/function.func-get-args.php) de php dice que func_get_args() devuelve un array que se compone de una lista de argumentos de una función.

Si queres hacer de otra manera es seria pasar parámetros a tu función o pasar por Get o post. Ya depende de vos. Ejemplo:

Por POST:

```
function Insertar_Datos() { 
    global $Conectar;

    // Digamos que viene de un formulario por post tus valores.
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];

    $InuevoArticulo = Insertar_Datos("Tabla" , "`id`,`nombre`" , "'".mysqli_real_escape_string($Conectar, $id)."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($Conectar, $nombre)."'");
    $RDatos = mysqli_query($Conectar, $InuevoArticulo);
    if (!$RDatos) { 
        http_response_code(500); 
        print(mysqli_error($Conectar)); 
    }else{ 
         http_response_code(200); 
         echo "ok";
    }
    return $RDatos;
}
```

Otra forma seria pasarle por parámetros a tu función:

```
function Insertar_Datos($id, $nombre) { 
    global $Conectar;

    $InuevoArticulo = Insertar_Datos("Tabla" , "`id`,`nombre`" , "'".mysqli_real_escape_string($Conectar, $id)."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($Conectar, $nombre)."'");
    $RDatos = mysqli_query($Conectar, $InuevoArticulo);
    if (!$RDatos) { 
        http_response_code(500); 
        print(mysqli_error($Conectar)); 
    }else{ 
         http_response_code(200); 
         echo "ok";
    }
    return $RDatos;
}
```

Comment: Realmente la forma q me comentas por post es igual q lo q yo estoy haciendo solo que no pasas los valores por finc_get_args y tienes que escribirlos en la consulta haciendo la funcion casi exclusiva para insertar artículos. la gracia de esa funcion es que te permite con una sola función utilizarla para cualquier tabla o cualquier valor sin tener que estar declarándolos. Osea lo que tu pones Insertar_Datos($id, $nombre) yo lo hago sin definir nada ahi y lo capturo con get_args simplemente creando un array con get_args y luego recuperando parámetros simplemente diciéndoles en que posición esta.

Comment: Realmente solo necesito saber si existe alguna forma de que a $Parametros[2] le pueda meter el mysqli_real_escape_string($Conectar,XXX) automáticamente y yo solo pasar por la funcion el dato por post... Creo que me he liado yo solo XD muchísimas gracias de todas formas por tu ayuda